# Add column based on multiple column conditions SQL

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, datatables

I have two mock tables like this:

Table1:

| ID | Type |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | EE |
| 2 | MM |
| 3 | EE |

Table2:

| ID | Col1 | Col2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Red | Yes |
| 2 | Blue | Yes |
| 3 | Red | No |

I would like an SQL query that adds a new column to Table 2 which is identified according to the following logic:
Electrical: Type: EE AND Col1: Red AND Col2: Yes
Mechanic: Type: MM AND Col1: Blue AND Col2: Yes

I expecting this result:

Table2:

| ID | Col1 | Col2 | NewColumn |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Red | Yes | Electric |
| 2 | Blue | Yes | Mechanic |
| 3 | Red | No |  |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can implement that logic almost exactly as you wrote it, in a `case expression` like so:

```
case 
    when Type = 'EE' and Col1 = 'Red' AND Col2 = 'Yes' then 'Electric'
    when Type = 'MM' AND Col1 = 'Blue' AND Col2 = 'Yes' then 'Mechanic'
end
```

as a select query, note here you should include table aliases for each column reference:

```
select
    t1.id, t1.type, t2.col1, t2.col2,
    case 
        when t1.Type = 'EE' and t2.Col1 = 'Red' AND t2.Col2 = 'Yes' then 'Electric'
        when t1.Type = 'MM' AND t2.Col1 = 'Blue' AND t2.Col2 = 'Yes' then 'Mechanic'
    end as NewColumn
from table1 as t1
inner join table2 as t2 on t1.id = t2.id
```